# At what inheritance level to store a dependency pointer when both dependency and dependent are polymorphic?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, dependencies, polymorphism, smart-pointers

I'm currently dealing with a situation where a polymorphic object has an injected dependency which is also polymorphic. My question is about the best way for the first family of classes to have behavior common to the family, requiring a call to a virtual method first defined in the top base class of the second family. Specifically, about where to store the owning smart pointer to the dependency - in the base, in derived classes, or in both places. (This question is about using smart pointers for the task, but a similar problem exists when using references or raw pointers for DI.)

I'll use some example base classes Worker and Job to illustrate. Every Worker owns one Job, constructor-injected. DerivedWorkers might require the user to inject a specific DerivedJob, and call methods specific to that DerivedJob. Every Worker must have public method get_location(), and the logic for this function is the same for all Workers, and it requires a call to a virtual method get_hours() defined in Job and overrode by its children. These are the three strategies I've come up with, "pointer in base and derived," "pointer in derived only," and "pointer in base only":

```
class Job
{
public:
    virtual ~Job();
    virtual Hours_t get_hours();
};

class DerivedJob : public Job
{
public:
    virtual Hours_t get_hours();
    void derived_specific_method();
};
```

Strategy 1: Pointer in base and derived

```
class Worker
{
public:
    Worker(std::shared_ptr<Job> job) : my_job(job) {}
    virtual ~Worker();
    Location_t get_location()
    {
        return some_logic(my_job->get_hours());
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Job> my_job; //cannot be unique_ptr
};

class DerivedWorker : public Worker
{
public:
    DerivedWorker(std::shared_ptr<DerivedJob> derivedJob) : Worker(derivedJob), my_derived_job(derivedJob) {}
    void derived_specific_duty()
    {
        my_derived_job->derived_specific_method();
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<DerivedJob> my_derived_job;
};
```

Strategy 2: pointer in derived only

```
class Worker //abstract
{
public:
    virtual ~Worker();
    virtual Location_t get_location() = 0;
};

class DerivedWorker : public Worker
{
public:
    DerivedWorker(std::unique_ptr<DerivedJob> derivedJob) : my_derived_job(derivedJob) {}
    virtual Location_t get_location()
    {
        return some_logic(my_derived_job->get_hours());
    }
    void derived_specific_duty()
    {
        my_derived_job->derived_specific_method();
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<DerivedJob> my_derived_job;
};
```

Strategy 3: pointer in base only

```
class Worker
{
public:
    Worker(std::unique_ptr<Job> job) : my_job(job) {}
    virtual ~Worker();
    Location_t get_location()
    {
        return some_logic(my_job->get_hours());
    }
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<Job> my_job;
};

class DerivedWorker : public Worker
{
public:
    DerivedWorker(std::unique_ptr<DerivedJob> derivedJob) : Worker(derivedJob) {}
    void derived_specific_duty()
    {
        dynamic_cast<DerivedJob*>(my_job.get())->derived_specific_method();
    }
};
```

Each comes with downsides and I'm trying to figure out if there's a fourth method I'm missing, if there's an idiomatic or "best" way of doing this, or if I'm missing some refactoring trick that makes this type of dependency pattern obsolete.

For 1, "pointers in base and derived," the drawback is that you can't use unique_ptr even if each Job is owned by only one Worker, because each Worker technically can own several smart pointers to the same Job. This might be a problem if Workers are frequently moved, or Jobs are swapped between Workers, due to the cache cohesion slowdowns introduced by moving shared_ptrs. This is the strategy I'm currently leaning towards.

For 2, "pointer in derived only," the drawback is a ton of code duplication. get_location() has to be virtual despite being almost exactly the same code for all Workers. In addition, now Worker may have to be abstract. (In this particular example, you could avoid this by making a null value for Location_t, but that's not always feasible in real applications of this problem.)

For 3, "pointer in base only," the drawback is having to use dynamic_cast, which is a huge code smell for a reason. Huge runtime costs, having to add in checks for the failed cast case, etc.

Comment: is there some specific  context where it needs to be so *overwhelminly* difficult?

Comment: "every worker owns one job" - why `std::shared_ptr` then?

Comment: clarify what you need: add some use case, what is the problem and the desired result of your solution?

Comment: A more concrete use case would be a dependency which implements drivers for a family of hardware which have the same purpose but different electrical interfaces, and a dependent which implements tasks you want to accomplish with the hardware. I wanted to use the Worker/Job analogy because it seems more straightforward to understand.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik that's exactly the downside with the strategy of storing the pointer twice in base and derived, in that using unique_ptr becomes impossible. Without that snag, the choice would be pretty clear and I wouldn't have posted a question.

Comment: if you want to use inheritence, you need a proper interface for both `IWorker` and `IJob`, and store an `std::unique_ptr<IJob>` in your base *implementation* class as a protected member. If you don't whant to use a protected member, use just  `IJob*` in inheriting classes. In general it is very unclear what you need.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik adding the extra layer of inheritance, while good practice in many ways (but omitted here for brevity), does not address the problem, which is with both the location *and type* of the pointer. What you describe is also what I described as "pointer in base only" with just an extra layer of inheritance. It still faces the problem of needing to upcast to access derived-specific extensions to the class.

Comment: well, given your example, I don't understand why `DerivedJob::derived_specific_method` is called by `DerivedSpecificWorker`, when it can be called be `DerivedJob` itself in its overriden implementation of `get_hours` or some other `jeneric_method`.

Comment: Suffice it to say that derived_specific_method()s can be very, very different between DerivedJobs. For brevity, they take no arguments and have no return in this example. But in my real problem the derived_specific_method()s have essentially no similarities between Jobs and may use totally unrelated argument and return types, and there might be 2 of them in one DerivedJob and 5 in another. Perhaps I have stripped too much context out of my example, but I wanted to make it general so the answers are useful to others as well as myself.

Comment: stick to *SOLID*, particularly revisit *Dependency inversion* and try to rethink your desing approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a variant of 2. :

Instead of `virtual Location_t get_location() = 0;` better to have `virtual Job& get_job() = 0;`, so you can use covariant return type in derived class, and implementation of `get_location()` is not duplicated.

```
class Worker // abstract
{
public:
    virtual ~Worker() = default;
    virtual Job& get_job() = 0;

    Location_t get_location() { return some_logic(get_job().get_hours()); }
};

class DerivedWorker : public Worker
{
public:
    explicit DerivedWorker(std::unique_ptr<DerivedJob> derivedJob) : my_job(std::move(derivedJob)) {}

    DerivedJob& get_job() override { return *my_job;}

    void derived_specific_duty() { my_job->derived_specific_method(); }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<DerivedJob> my_job;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this does solve the biggest problem with the pointer-in-derived strategy! This is an open ended question, so I'll wait a day to mark as accepted, but this definitely addresses the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 - problem is duplication of data which is both overhead and source of bugs.

Method 3 - problem is the dynamic cast - it is a very slow cast. You could've used only static_cast but it is messy to constantly make the cast. Since the base class has little to nothing implemented it is not worth to store the type in it since it only restricts its use.

Method 2 - is the only sensible method of the 3 you provided.

Aside from that, I also question the purpose of these virtual classes - do they serve purpose? Simply having a common function is not good enough of a reason to make a shared base class. It actually needs to helpful. Don't just make base classes because they said "object oriented is good".

Also, I'd also consider template methods. In cases when your objects are numerous and require fast processing object oriented tends to fall short of template based methods.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on the issues that could crop up from duplication of data in method 1? I had assumed that other than losing the ability to use unique_ptr, there were no downsides to duplicating storage of a smart pointer within one object.

Comment: @John imagine your collegue makes or modifies a DerivedWorker class and forgets to update one of the pointers in some place.